# PayPal card issue

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I create token card using paypal Payment Methods Token API, then i store vault_id and use it when creating order. All that in sandbox mode.

```
const order = {
    intent: 'CAPTURE',
    purchase_units: [
        {
            amount: {
                currency_code: 'USD',
                value: `10.00`,
            },
        },
    ],

};

if (vaultId) {
    order.payment_source = {
        card: {
            vault_id: vaultId
        }
    };
}
```

My question is: **I want to test 3d secure, so i tried to use cards from 3d secure scenario,
but capture completed immediately without any 3ds confirmation.**

Answer (score 0):

Vault has its own test cards, which are separate from 3D secure test cards. The two cannot be tested at the same time.